Multi Wire Branch Circuit for Kitchen Small Appliances Circuit, AFCI and GFCI required
I need to redo the electrical in my kitchen. I want to add an EMT ring around the kitchen with two lives and a neutral inside in a multi wire branch circuit configuration for the two required small appliance circuits.
I like this for these reasons:

save copper
very resistant to mix ups with the two circuits where a receptacle could connect a live from one circuit and neutral from another

But, kitchens require GFCI and AFCI. I want to use a combination breaker for this, since that's cheaper than many GFCI and AFCI outlets. But, a normal pair of combination breakers would trip as soon as both circuits are run at the same time. So, it seems to me that I need a double pole AFCI+GFCI breaker. But, a supply house told me that these don't exist (at least for my panel), and I can't find any (Eaton CH).
I considered AFCI + GFCI on each outlet with dumb 2 pole or 1 pole breakers. This seems to me to violate NEC 2020 210.12 because all of the cases where a receptacle is used require that you run the other receptacles off it, but I don't want to separate out neutral after the first outlet because the panel is very close to the kitchen.
Am I missing anything here that can eliminate these trade-offs? It seems to me that I'll need an extra neutral, but I can't think of any reason that afci+gfci 2 pole breakers shouldn't exist, so presumably there's some other way to do this since otherwise such a breaker would be useful and would thus exist.

What version of NEC is your jurisdiction using?

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact 2020

Looks pretty clear then that you need AFCI in the kitchen (and most other rooms). Asked only because we have had some questions where it turns out something (AFCI or GFCI depending on the particular situation) wasn't actually required because OP's location didn't require it yet.

See also MWBC for split kitchen receptacle

I do a lot of work in EMT. You are being guided by several misunderstandings.
First, you are already required to identify which neutral wire is with which hot wire. NEC 200.4(B).  That is easily done one of several ways:

Use gray neutral, it's a legal neutral color
If multiple hot colors, mark the neutral with colored tape, paint, sharpie or shrink tube matching the hot color
If one hot color, mark both hot and neutral with the same color (e.g. black-red and white-red are one circuit, black-blue and white-blue are the other).

I've been known to use all at once when I have as many as 8 circuits crossing through a box.  And while I have a complicated and nuanced relationship with MWBCs, the fact is, THHN is cheap.
Second, you know GFCI protection only requires protecting outlets, not the wiring in the walls, so a GFCI at every outlet is fine. (true).  However, you think AFCI works the same way and it does not.
The AFCI protection must be at the breaker, or, if in a metal jacket, it can be at the first receptacle. Beyond that point, the wiring itself must be in the AFCI-protected zone.
Third, and I wonder if this is news to you -- AFCIs and GFCIs are capable of protecting a downline. THHN is laughably cheaper than GFCI receptacles, so it is dumb to save the neutral wire between 1st and 2nd receptacle location but then have to use 2 more xFCI receptacles or a costly 2-pole A/GFCI breaker.
I would run metal jacketed cable or metal conduit from panel to 1st receptacle, make that a 2-gang box, specifically a 4-11/16" square x 2-1/8" box with a 2-gang mud ring. Because it has elbow room for the G/AFCI combo receptacles, and I'd have 2 there.  Then I'd continue onward with 4 wires (2 hot 2 neutral, no ground wire needed in EMT) to plain receptacles and either make them 2-gang or leapfrog (outlets 2-4-6 are on L1 and 3-5-7 are on L2).  I would not bother splitting the receptacle.

I double-checked the Eaton CH catalog and they have double-pole AFCI and double-pole GFCI and single-pole AFCI/GFCI but no double-pole AFCI/GFCI.
Saving copper is nice. But in the grand scheme of things, a few extra feet of 12 AWG isn't that much compared to the cost of EMT, AFCI breakers, etc.
As far as:

very resistant to mix ups with the two circuits where a receptacle could connect a live from one circuit and neutral from another

that's taken care of by wiring properly and double-checking everything. Not a big deal. If you tag your neutrals with tape (black and red to match their partner hots) before you fish them through then there won't be any confusion.
The one thing you lose though is the ability to have a split with circuit 1 on the top and circuit 2 on the bottom of receptacles all around the kitchen. But you have other options, including:

Alternate receptacles by box. In the first receptacle of each string you put a GFCI/receptacle. You can even color code the receptacles so you know at a glance which ones are on each circuit.
Put two duplex receptacles in each box instead of 1. In the first receptacle of each string you put a GFCI/receptacle. Then all the left receptacles are on one circuit and all the right receptacles are on the other circuit. Nobody ever complains about too many receptacles in the kitchen.


"The one thing you lose though is the ability to have a split with circuit 1 on the top and circuit 2 on the bottom" Can't I just break the bridge and connect them that way? Sharing grounds between circuits is allowed, especially if the conduit is the ground as I plan to do.

You can. But the first in each chain can't do that because GFCI/receptacles are always single hot/neutral in, single hot/neutral out - the second set of screws isn't "bridge or not bridge", it is load vs. line.
